# passing data by POST method between views in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have data in a particular view page(collected from the user) which I need to send to another view page which has a form needing this data. Now I can use:-
1.  post method of javascript(jquery)

```
$().redirect('/Events/Create', {'arg1': 'value1', 'arg2': 'value2'});
```

or

1. A form:-

> $('#inset_form').html(' < form action="/Events/Create"
>   method="post"style="display:none;">< input type="text" name="lat"
>   value="' + latitude + '" />< /form>');
>
> document.forms['vote'].submit();

Now my question is, which method should be chosen?

Also, the '/Events/Create' page has form in the following way:-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <div class="editor-label">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lat)
  </div>
   <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lat)---------> THIS field accepts the POSTed data
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lat)
   </div>

   <div>
       ....OTHER INPUT FIELDS.....
   </div>

   <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
}
```

So, my next question is how do I make the text box 'lat' created by @Html.EditorFor in the form show the POSTed data as its default value. Then, the user can fill other fields and then submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

As per HTTP standards, if a call is not changing the state of the website (i.e. data), you should use a GET request. This means you should provide the user with a link including the proper query string to populate the form on the /Events/Create page.

Also, keep in mind you never send data from view to view in MVC. Everything goes through a controller action so make sure your "Create" action on the "Events" controller accepts the proper arguments to populate the form for submission. If the Model.lat variable has a value in it when rendering the view, the text box will be prepopulated with that value.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to POST the data to the second form? If you want to show the form and load it with default values, create a GET action method for it and pass the default values in the url. Although there's nothing stopping you having two POST methods for the same view, the normal approach would be to load the form using a GET, then POST back the data after editing.

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Create(string lat)
 {
     MyView view = new MyView();
     view.lat = lat;
     View(view);
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create(MyView view)
 {
     //process posted data after editing
 }
```

The view object here is a ViewModel class containing properties for the data that you will edit on the form. Make your View strongly typed to this ViewModel type.

To invoke the GET method from your jQuery (above):

```
window.location = "Events/Create?lat=myValue";
```

Comment: @Paul...what I meant by default was that a field in the form (i.e. lat) will be determined by user's action on a particular page...to make things clear, here lat is latitude which is the latitude value of where a user clicks on a map...so 'default' might be a misnomer

Comment: @avinash, I think I understood what you meant. You want to pass the value of lat from the page where the user clicks the map, to your Create view. My solution will do that.